# py2exe: Skip archive ignored

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm probably making a stupid error somewhere but i can't find it. Here is my setup.py:

```
import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup

setup(windows=['Gui.py'],
    data_files = [('Drivers', ['Drivers/chromedriver.exe',
                               'Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe']
                 )],
    options={
        "py2exe":{
            "skip_archive": True,
            "unbuffered": True,
            "optimize": 2
        }
})
```

The command i'm running is:

**python setup.py py2exe**

All of my files are in setup.py (no subdirectories)

I'm using:

- **python 3.4.2**
- **py2exe 0.9.2.2**

The error i'm getting is that in /dist archive.zip is still here and is not divided in subdirectories.

Any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your data_files definition doesn't look right, shouldn't it be:

```
data_files = [('Drivers', ['Drivers/chromedriver.exe',
                   'Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe'])],
```

i.e. a ',' after 'Drivers'

Is the error you are getting an exception? or ....?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I'm not getting any error. and the files "chromedriver.exe" and "IEDriverServer.exe" are where i expect them. But i will try your suggestion thank you. Maybe it will fix it.

Comment: It seems it was a typo when i wrote the question. I had the ',' after driver in my file. i will edit the question.